# why global variable in recursion uses more memory than a local variable?

Tags: c, recursion, memory-management, global-variables

I have 2 versions of code in C.

Version 1:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int globalA = 10000;
int globalB = 0;

int recursion(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a = *a - 1;
    *b += *a;
    if (*a < 1) {
        sleep(30);
        return *b;
    } else {
        return recursion(a, b);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("globalA: %i\n", globalA);
    printf("globalB: %i\n", globalB);

    recursion(&globalA, &globalB);

    printf("globalA: %i\n", globalA);
    printf("globalB: %i\n", globalB);
    return 0;
}
```

And Version 2 – the same code but without pointers:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int globalA = 10000;
int globalB = 0;

int recursion(int a, int b)
{
    a = a - 1;
    b += a;
    if (a < 1) {
        sleep(30);
        return b;
    } else {
        return recursion(a, b);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("globalA: %i\n", globalA);
    printf("globalB: %i\n", globalB);
    recursion(globalA, globalB);
    printf("globalA: %i\n", globalA);
    printf("globalB: %i\n", globalB);
    return 0;
}
```

I call console command vmmap on os x when the code is on line 12 – **sleep(30);**

My question is why vmmap shows for the first version this line for stack:

```
                                VIRTUAL RESIDENT    DIRTY  SWAPPED VOLATILE   NONVOL    EMPTY   REGION
REGION TYPE                        SIZE     SIZE     SIZE     SIZE     SIZE     SIZE     SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced)
===========                     ======= ========    =====  ======= ========   ======    =====  =======
Stack                             8192K     476K     476K       0K       0K       0K       0K        2
```

and for the second version this:

```
Stack                             8192K     316K     316K       0K       0K       0K       0K        2
```

So the **resident size** of stack for version 1 is grater than for version 2.

I thought that in version 2 every call of recursion will make a new copy of variables **a** and **b** in each new stack frame. As a result it will consume more memory in stack with each call to recursion.

And in version 1 there is no need to make a new copy of variables  **a** and **b** because they are passed by reference, and the variables given by reference are global, so **globalA** must be in the **.data memory segment**, and **globalB** in **.bss segment**. As a result less space needed in stack.

Am i wrong? Please explain to me where is the trick here.

P.S. Code was compiled with clang

Comment: These two codes are doing different things, it's quite incorrect to compare them.

Comment: `printf("%zu, %zu\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(int*));`

Comment: @EugeneSh. hm, why they are doing different things?

Comment: @WhozCraig 4 and 8

Comment: At the very least - the first variant has a side effect of modifying the globals.

Comment: @EugeneSh. what you mean? Can you explain?

Comment: Your `globalA` and `globalB` are going to have different values after this function is done. In the first variant.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, i did it because i thought that it would save more space on the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the "globals" case, you don't have to create new copies of the variables `globalA` and `globalB` on the stack for each recursion, but you *do* still have to create new copies of the pointer variables `a` and `b` on the stack for each recursion.  You don't say what operating system or ABI you are using, but I expect it is one where `sizeof(int *)` is larger than `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: I use macOS High Sierra version 10.13.4

Comment: Ok, so now i assume that using global variables in recursions is pointless, right?

Comment: "I expect it is one where sizeof(int *) is larger than sizeof(int)"
Yes you are right! I see that sizeof(int) is 4 and sizeof(int *) is 8.
Thank you!

Comment: "but you do still have to create new copies of the pointer variables a and b on the stack for each recursion". – You mean the arguments passed to function recursion?

Comment: Yes, I mean the arguments. In recursive functions, arguments take up space on the stack just like local variables. (I say "in recursive functions" because the compiler may be going to some trouble to _avoid_ pushing arguments on the stack as much as possible ... but that doesn't work for recursive functions.)

Comment: This particular use of global variables in a recursive function is indeed pointless, but I would hesitate to say it's _always_ pointless.  (It is always thread-unsafe, though, unless by global you mean `thread_local`.)